# When I drag a window to the side of the screen, this happens. What does it mean?

Tags: windows-8-preview

What's the use and sense behind this feature of Windows 8. The feature is depicted in the image attached:

[image]

I had to take a photo with my mobile camera as the "Print Screen" button was not working in this area.

Comment: Despite my answer, yes, I don't understand the intention behind some of the new features of Windows 8 for desktop users either.

Comment: @Canha: If they disabled them, you would answer questions like "HOW ENABLE SNAP ON WIN8 DESKTOP??? M$ SUCKS FOR DIZABLIN THT!!!"

Comment: @Oliver: our eternal fate! However having the option is always nice, having none annoys me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are showing us is the interface for putting 2 applications side to side (Metro Snap). For example, the desktop showing on the right side and a metro application on the left (like the music player).

Usually, some of the functionalities of the application with less space will be hidden.

[image: Metro Snap]

Read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8#Shell_and_user_interface